# Ouath 2.0 with Asp.net Web Api 2 with only external login like google etc

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, asp.net-web-api2, c#-5.0

I am trying to implement Oauth 2.0 security integration with Asp.net web api 2 but only with external logins like google.I am pretty new for Oauth thing.

Can any one suggest any good tutorial/ example with only external login.

I do not want local user to register  etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google describes all the options pretty well on their website [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

The most important steps are:

1. Register your application at [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)
2. Enable all your required scopes
3. Specify the allowed callback url to your website

Basically it works like this:

1. You redirect the user to your /api/Account/Login page
2. This Action method will redirect the user to the Google login page
3. User logs in and gets redirected to the callback url you specified (and approved in the Developer Console)
4. This callback url Action method will ask Google for a token based on the authorization code.

Following code snipped should get you started:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly string _clientId = "YourCliendId";

    [Route("Login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetLogin()
    {
        string scope = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Space Seperated list of scopes");
        string redirectUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://YourWebsiteURL/api/Account/OAuthCallback");
        string accessType = "Either online or offline";
        string requestUri = string.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&access_type={3}&approval_prompt=auto&include_granted_scopes=true", _clientId, redirectUri, scope, accessType);

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(requestUri);
        return response;
    }

    [Route("Logout")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetLogout()
    {
        //Optionally if you need to be able to logout...
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/logout");
        return response;
    }

    [Route("OAuthCallback")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOAuthCallback(string error)
    {
        //This would be a nice place to include some logging...
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://YourWebsiteURL");
        return response;
    }

    [Route("OAuthCallback")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOAuthCallback(string code, string scope)
    {
        string redirectUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://YourWebsiteURL/api/Account/OAuthCallback");
        string postMessage = string.Format("code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}&grant_type=authorization_code", code, _clientId, "YourGoogleSecretCode", redirectUri);

        string jsonMessage;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //Convert the authorization code to a token
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
            jsonMessage = client.UploadString("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "POST", postMessage);
        }
        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonMessage);

        //Do something with the token. E.g. put it in a cookie / header ... and pass it to the client.
    }
}

public class Token
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
}

public class TokenInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("issued_to")]
    public string IssuedTo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("audience")]
    public string Audience { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("scope")]
    public string Scope { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("verified_email")]
    public bool VerifiedEmail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("access_type")]
    public string AccessType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW. If you need to later on validate the token you can use the following code:

```cs
string requestUri = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={0}", token.AccessToken);
string tokenInfoMessage;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    tokenInfoMessage = client.DownloadString(requestUri);
}
TokenInfo tokenInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenInfo>(tokenInfoMessage);

//Don't forget to validate the Audience and Scope, because the token might be a valid token (but not meant for your website).
if (tokenInfo.Audience == _clientId && tokenInfo.Scope.Contains("All the scopes that you provided") && tokenInfo.UserId == "TheGoogleUserIdYouWantToCheck")
{
    //Looks valid, so continue with whatever you want to do...
}
```